# Link error when using the __cpuid() in <intrin.h>?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, cpuid

The error says:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinCPUID_Init referenced in function 
"public: static void __cdecl CCapturer::GetCPUVendorId(void)" 
 (?GetCPUVendorId@CCapturer@@SAXXZ)
```

but it doesn't point out which lib I should add in MSDN [_cpuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

How to solve it ?

Comment: Please show declaration and Call of `CCapturer::GetCPUVendorId`

Comment: declaration public: static void GetCPUVendorId(); definition void CCapturer::GetCPUVendorId(){...};call CCapturer::GetCPUVendorId()

Comment: this is a definition of function i think the problem is in the calling can u please show that?

Comment: @christopher please, please, don't post additional information to your question in comments, put them in question itself. It is nor readable, nor helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to your question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b80068ac-e17b-4f21-85fd-1d87fdc9b6b6/link-error-when-using-the-cpuid-in-intrinh?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was also used by the fddshow-tryout installer (I don't know what that is) and is defined in `WinCPUID.dll`

```
external     'WinCPUID_Init@files:WinCPUID.dll cdecl';
```

I found a match for WinCPUID_Init symbol here:

http://code.google.com/p/notepad2-mod/source/browse/branches/inno/distrib/cpu_detection.iss?r=616

The code header says

```
// The script is taken from the ffdshow-tryouts installer
// http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/
```

And later

```
// functions to detect CPU
function WinCPUID_Init(msGetFrequency: Integer; var pInfo: TCPUInfo): Integer;
external     'WinCPUID_Init@files:WinCPUID.dll cdecl';
// function to get system information
procedure GetSystemInfo(var lpSystemInfo: TSystemInfo); external 'GetSystemInfo@kernel32.dll stdcall';


procedure CPUCheck();
var
  CPUInfo: TCPUInfo;
begin
  WinCPUID_Init(0, CPUInfo);

  if (CPUInfo.bIsInitialized = 0) then begin
    // something went wrong
  end
  else begin
    if (CPUInfo.bSSE_Supported  = 1) then begin
      cpu_sse  := true;
    end;
    if (CPUInfo.bSSE2_Supported = 1) then begin
      cpu_sse2 := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```